# How to hide a snackbar on tap?

Tags: flutter, flushbar

I used snackbar from `another_flushbar` package.

```
Flushbar(
   title: "Title",
   message: 'some message here',
   duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
   flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
)..show(context);
```

How to hide it on tap? There is a callback that registers the user's click anywhere.

```
 final OnTap? onTap;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `inkWell` or `GestureDetector`

```
Inkwell(
onTap:(){
Navigator.of(context).pop();
},
child: Flushbar(
   title: "Title",
   message: 'some message here',
   duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
   flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
)..show(context),
);
```

you can also try with `mainButton`

```
Flushbar(
   title: "Title",
   message: 'some message here',
   duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
   flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
   mainButton: FlatButton(
                             onPressed: () {
                                 flush.dismiss(true); // result = true
                               },
                             child: Text(
                               "Dismiss",
                               style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
                             ),
                           ),
)..show(context);
```

Comment: There is no need for outer wigdet. The inner onTap works with `Navigator.of(context).pop();`

Comment: you go for second one i hope work for you

Comment: Local variable 'flush' can't be referenced before it is declared.
Try moving the declaration to before the first use, or renaming the local variable so that it doesn't hide a name from an enclosing scope.

how to use   ```flush.dismiss(true)```  here?